# How to get height and width of image variant?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I need to return image url to specific variant and return height and width of this variant image

```
variant = image.variant(resize: '1000x1000')
json.image_url(rails_representation_url(variant))
json.image_width # TODO: best way to receive width of variant
json.image_height # TODO: best way to receive height of variant
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it next way

```
variant = image.variant(resize: '1000x1000').processed
path = variant.service.path_for(variant.key)
width, height = MiniMagick::Image.new(path)[:dimensions]

json.image_url(rails_representation_url(variant))
json.image_width(width)
json.image_height(height)
```